# what's wrong in int=float%int;?

Tags: c

```
float m; 
int lftovr,x;
scanf("%.2f", &m);
lftovr = m%100;
x=m/100;
```

why does it show error:

```
||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
E:\c programme\naeem\change.c||In function 'main':|
E:\c programme\naeem\change.c|6|error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'float' and 'int')|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *constraint* such that both operands of the `%` operator must have integer type:

> **6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**
> ...
> **Constraints**
> 2     Each of the operands shall have arithmetic type. *The operands of the `%` operator shall
> have integer type.*

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

Emphasis added.

If you need to get a remainder on division of `float` values, use `fmod()`:

```
float lftovr = fmod( m, 100.0f );
```

Answer (score 8):

Because the modulus division '%' apply just to integers, not to float. This is because there is no remainder if it is not an integer division.

Comment: Not sure what the OP wants to do but it might be `((int)m)%100+m-(int)m`

Comment: There is `fmod`